# Java enum method

Tags: java, enums

The following code has no problem with compiling and running. But my question is what is the use of public `int getValue(int bid)` [ NOT `getValues(int bid)` ? How will i call that method?

```
package com.main;
public class Bridge {

    public enum Suites{
        CLUB(20), DIMOND(20), HEARTS(30), SPADES(40){ 
            public int getValue(int bid){
                return ((bid-1)*30)+40;
            }
        };
        private int points;
        Suites(int points){
            this.points = points;

        }

        public int getValues(int bid){
            return points*bid;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Suites.CLUB.getValues(3));
        System.out.println(Suites.HEARTS.points);
        System.out.println(Suites.values());
    }

}
```

```
The out put is : 
60
30
[Lcom.main.Bridge$Suites;@2a139a55
```

Comment: It has no purpose and cannot be called, except through reflection.  It's likely a typo and I'm voting to close as such.

Comment: In English, the category is called "Suits", and the values are "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", and "Hearts". You have a few typos there.

Answer (score 0):

The only use case for the getValue method specified for SPADES is if a method with the same and and signature is specified for the Suites enum, e.g. like this:

```
public class Test {

    public enum Suites {
        CLUB(20),
        DIMOND(20),
        HEARTS(30),
        SPADES(40) {
            @Override
            public int getValue(int bid) {
                return ((bid - 1) * 30) + 40;
            }
        };
        private int points;

        Suites(int points) {
            this.points = points;

        }

        public int getValue(int bid) {
            return bid;
        }

        public int getValues(int bid) {
            return points * bid;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Suites suite : Suites.values()) {
            System.out.println(suite.name() + ": getValue: " + suite.getValue(1));
        }
    }
}
```

This will output

```
CLUB: getValue: 1
DIMOND: getValue: 1
HEARTS: getValue: 1
SPADES: getValue: 40
```